# Migration to Turkey for Iraqis

Tags: turkey

I am an Iraqi national and have a bachelor's degree in Information Technology.

1. What are the migration opportunities and regulations (student visas,
   work permits) in Turkey as of January 2017 for educated Iraqis
   currently living abroad?
2. Once living and studying/working there, how many years have to
   elapse until an Iraqi can be naturalized (acquire the Turkish
   nationality and passport)?
3. Does the current country of residence dictate one's chances of
   migrating to Turkey?

#### Inquiries about visas/permits

1. Are student visas obtainable after arrival in Turkey, or must they
   be obtained prior to arrival?
2. Once there, does buying a property in Turkey qualify an Iraqi to
   obtain a residence permit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2016, Iraqi nationals have to pre-apply for either an electronic or a paper visa to enter the country. Those who hold a valid visa or residence permit issued by the US, UK, Ireland or a Schengen country are able to travel to [Turkey with only an electronic visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

Those who don't have to [apply for a visa online](http://www.goc.gov.tr/icerik/visa_917_1059) and then obtain it from a Turkish diplomatic consular mission.

The [Republic of Turkey Ministry of Interior Directorate General of Migration Management](http://www.goc.gov.tr/main/) web site provides a wealth of information, with easy links to visa application, residency requirements,  migration policies, etc.

Turkey has [6 types of residence permits](http://www.goc.gov.tr/main/Eng_3):

- short term residence permit: up to 2 years (which includes those who own property)
- family residence permit: up to 3 years
- student residence permit: for the duration of education
- long term residence permit: indefinite (after having lived in Turkey for 8 years)
- humanitarian residence permit: up to 1 year
- human trafficking victims residence permit: up to 3 years with 6 months renewals, initial permit 30 days